# Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error

Tags: django, settings, django-1.5

Once I change the `DEBUG = False`, my site will generate 500 (using wsgi & manage.py runserver), and there is no error info in Apache error log and it will run normally when I change `debug` to `True` .

I'm using Django 1.5 & Python 2.7.3
here is Apache access log and without any log in apache error log

```
www.beta800.net:80 222.247.56.11 - - [28/Feb/2013:13:42:28 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 257 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22"
www.beta800.net:80 222.247.56.11 - - [28/Feb/2013:13:42:28 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 257 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22"
www.beta800.net:80 222.247.56.11 - - [28/Feb/2013:13:42:28 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 257 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22"
```

Here is my settings file:

```
import os.path    
DEBUG = False 
#TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

HERE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ADMINS = (
    ('admin', 'xyzadmin@qq.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'zdm',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'passwd',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(HERE, 'static').replace('\\','/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(HERE, 'static').replace('\\','/')
S= os.path.join(HERE, 'static').replace('\\','/')

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/zdm/static',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '9a7!^gp8ojyk-^^d@*whuw!0rml+r+uaie4ur$(do9zz_6!hy0'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'zdm.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'zdm.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/zdm/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'zdm',
    'portal',
    'admin',
    'tagging',
)
```

Comment: Yes, i have add 403 & 404 500 html file in my templates dir

Comment: Do you have 500.html and 404.html and 403.html files in place? I think I recall having an issue with a deployed project that did not have those files in the root of my templates directory.

Comment: If your site is generating a 500 error there should be some info in the apache log, you might want to past a chunk of the end of the error log file for people to look at.

Comment: how did you handle or call the error? 500 will generate if you change your debug because the system didn't detect existing 404 templates

Comment: add some access log in my question. thanks

Comment: You might want to change your SECRET_KEY now that it's publicly available...

Comment: This isn't the answer for everyone. As shown below in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37218484/4028977, there could be many reasons why this is occurring. With some simple logging you can find out without guesswork.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

Django 1.5 introduced the [allowed hosts setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.5/#allowed-hosts-required-in-production) that is required for security reasons. A settings file created with Django 1.5 has this new section which you need to add:

```
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Add your host here like `['www.beta800.net']` or `['*']` for a quick test, [but don't use `['*']` for production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: Wow - this bit us hard. It really sucks that this setting is buried in the docs. Our production site wouldn't work with DEBUG = False. Thank you for pointing this out!!!

Comment: More on the security issues that introduced this setting: [Practical HTTP Host header attacks](http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html). Will definitely convince you not to use `['*']` in production.

Comment: bl. annoying that they don't even stick it in as a default value in settings.py, perhaps with an expanatory comment...

Comment: If your settings file comes from a django 1.5 installation, the configuration ALLOWED_HOSTS  will be there, with an explanatory comment (like what @hwjp wanted). If you add your own entry of ALLOWED_HOSTS (and have an existing , duplicated ALLOWED_HOSTS ) you will continue to get 500 error .

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why Django is becoming more and more frustrating to work with! Surelly those guys are much better programmers than me, but I really don't understand the decision to "fix" vulnerabilities at the application level, when the real and clean move would be to configure the server properly. Same goes for "template caching" and "persistent connections" ... Useless code that will never be used in a serious website; still is presented as the holy grail of programming! Maybe is just me, I've been wrong before!

Comment: So another funny thing is that it matters *where* in the settings file you define ALLOWED_HOSTS. Put it in the beginning - the error persisted. Moved to the end of the file - worked!

Comment: This solved my problem. [This Blog post](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/01/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error-solved.html) shows a detailed description of the error and solution. I had my server IP which I entered in the ALLOWED_HOSTS list to get rid of 500 error.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS is **NOT** the only issue, for me I had to make a 404.html and put it in the base level of my templates (not app level) - Also, you can make a 404 view and add a 404handler url but I think thats optional. 404.html fixed it

Comment: I set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `['*']` for testing purposes and still got a 500 after rebooting the server. No sign of trouble in the server log, only that damned HTTP 500. How do I obtain more error information without relying on `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem. It was related to `django-pipeline`'s behavior when the static hasn't been collected yet. As a general tip, placing a breakpoint in Django's `handle_uncaught_exception` method will help you figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Why is this marked the correct answer? An incorrect ALLOWED_HOSTS gives a server 400 error, not a server 500.

Comment: @Pieter how did you fix your issue? I had the exact same problem. When I remove the static reference, I don't get the error anymore

Comment: I don't recall, I'd need a time machine to ask myself... The breakpoint in Django's `handle_uncaught_exception` method still sounds like a useful trick though!

Answer (score 85):

I know this is late but I ended up here with a search for my error 500 with `DEBUG=False`, in my case it did turn out to be the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but I was using `os.environ.get('variable')` to populate the hosts, I did not notice this until I enabled logging, you can log all errors to file with the below and it will log even when `DEBUG=False`:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'mysite.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's much more useful to simply ask the framework itself what is wrong after using the production settings, instead of trying to guess.

Comment: Indeed, this is not something to wander around in the dark about. Just look at the error message you would normally see using this method.

In my case, I was missing a different setting in my settings.py that my app was looking for. All I needed was the log to track this down.

One important note: I added /path/to/my/django/ before the 'mysite.log' as shown in the docs example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#examples

Comment: I have spent hours looking for a solution, no use. according to this answer just use logging and you should have your problem, this is the best answer. Thanks OP!

Comment: My server errors do not seem to produce any logs! I have tried various logging configs to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my error. Turns out I needed to run collectstatic to collect some static assets from a package.

Comment: I added this to my settings and it tells me it wont run because of not having permission to access the log. I gave the permissions I even changed ownership of the log to root. I commented out this logging script but nothing. `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mysite.log'` `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'`

Comment: @Gorgonzola There could be a number of reasons why you get permission denied, Start with is the python application running as the user your expecting | ./mysite.log is a relative path is your PWD where you think it is. Is there some security blocking it such as SELINUX

Comment: @squareborg I tried figuring it out but nothing. Since I am developing I had the luxury of just loading a previous version and moved on. I gave permission to everything, erased the code. Tried to clear the tracks so to speak but it kept asking for access to that logfile which I touched and gave permissions just in case. It was a weird one, I could not say for sure.

Comment: @Gorgonzola if you have a sys admin in your team holla at them. They are best at troubleshooting permission denied.  Like I say there's a lot of things that can get in the way.

Comment: Where does `mysite.log` get placed? It's not in the root directory of my project on Heroku using `heroku run ls`.

Comment: This is the real solution!!! Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 62):

I encountered the same issue just recently in Django 2.0. I was able to figure out the problem by setting `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True`. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions

In my case, the error was `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'admin/css/base.css'`. I fixed that by locally running `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: I go the same thing but collectstatic did not fix it for me. Did you get a "can't be reached error"? In that case, how did you fix it?

Comment: Why is this so far down? This helps no matter what the reason for the error is.

Comment: This should be the answer to the question "How do I debug a 500 error in Django".

Comment: Note that according to the document linked in the answer, this shouldn't be enabled in production (without a complete understanding of what it does).

Answer (score 27):

In my case, reading docs of third party apps properly saved me.

The culprit? django_compressor

I had

```
{% load compress %}
{% compress css %}
 ... css files linked here ..
{% endcompress %}
```

`DEBUG = True` always gave me 500. To fix it, I needed a line in my settings to get it running

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = os.environ.get('COMPRESS_ENABLED', False)
```

Comment: Thanks that was the reason it didn't work for me, but doesn't that line disable django_compressor from doing its job?

Comment: @Fanckush Nope. No harm is involved. https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED Compressor would still be doing its job perfectly! Simply compress all your statics (like css), so that setting is thus useless as your assets are already compressed

Answer (score 20):

Its mid 2019 and I faced this error after a few years of developing with Django. Baffled me for an entire night! It wasn't allowed host (which should throw a 400), everything else checked out, finally did some error logging only to discover that some missing / or messed up static files manifest (after collectstatic) were screwing with the setup. Long story short, for those who are stumped AND SO HAPPEN ARE USING WHITENOISE OR THE DJANGO STATICFILE BACKEND WITH CACHE (manifest static files) , maybe this is for you.

1. Make sure you setup everything (as I did for the whitenoise backend...django backends read on nonetheless)  http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html
2. If error code 500 still shoots you down, take note on your settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE.

Set it to either (for whitenoise backend with compression)

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

or (leave as django default)

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage
```

All in all, THE PROBLEM seemed to come from the fact that this whitenoise cache + compression backend -->

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

or the django's own caching backend -->

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

...didnt quite work well for me, since my css was referencing some other sources which may be mixed up during collectstatic / backend caching. This issue is also potentially highlighted in http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#storage-troubleshoot

Comment: Changing to this  - `whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage` - worked for me.

Comment: While I still have some other things to figure out and fix, this seems like it was the answer for me. One of these days I will fully understand how static files work in production. I don't know why it confuses me so much.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me crazy. This error only happens in a remote environment with `DEBUG` set to `False`.

Answer (score 13):

Right, in Django 1.5 if `DEBUG = False`, configure ALLOWED_HOSTS, adding domains without the port number. example:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

Comment: For whatever reason, using 'localhost' didn't work for me. I had to use the IP '127.0.0.1' instead. I was also able to use '*' if you're freaking out and just want it to work. I wouldn't advise doing that in production, however.

OSX running Django 1.4.20

Answer (score 13):

You must also check your URLs all over the place. When the `DEBUG` is set to `False`, all URLs without trailing `/` are treated as a bug, unlike when you have `DEBUG = True`, in which case Django will append `/` everywhere it is missing. So, in short, make sure all links end with a slash EVERYWHERE.

Comment: just use reverse and url tag and you should be fine

Comment: setting `DEBUG=False` can unveil import errors as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676453/what-are-functional-differences-between-debug-true-and-false-in-django/25754343#25754343

Comment: even links to js and css assets?

Comment: @amchugh89: no, just "django" URLs

Comment: My issue is that whitenoise wasn't able to find some image and was throwing ValueError. I also couldn't find it, but didn't know how to tell whitenoise not to look for it. So I turned whitenoise off, use the django static serve and now I can run debug=False in prod. Obviously not ideal :(

Answer (score 9):

**Complementing the main answer**
It is annoying to change the ALLOWED_HOSTS and DEBUG global constants in `settings.py` when switching between development and production.
I am using this code to set these setting automatically:

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == "server_name":
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".your_domain_name.com",]
    ...
else:
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1",]
    ...
```

If you use macOS you could write a more generic code:

```
if socket.gethostname().endswith(".local"): # True in your local computer
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1",]
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth - I was getting a 500 with `DEBUG = False` on some pages only. Tracing back the exception with pdb revealed a missing asset (I suspect the `{% static ... %}` template tag was the culprit for the 500.

Comment: This was my issue also, the base template that the custom 404 page was referencing used the static tag but did not include the {% load static %} at the top. I didn't notice it elsewhere because my other templates had this line but makes sense to put it in the base anyhow as it refers to static files all over the place.

Comment: Same solution here - I was using `static` to include a CSS file that didn't exist.

Comment: this was the most hilarious problem I have ever had. Quizzed me for 2 hours straight.

Answer (score 8):

I was searching and testing more about this issue and I realized that static files directories specified in settings.py can be a cause of this, so fist, we need to run this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

in settings.py, the code should look something like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a hilarious story for all. After reaching this page I said "Eureka! I'm saved. That MUST be my problem." So I inserted the required `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in setting.py and... nothing. Same old 500 error. And no, it wasn't for lack of a 404.html file.

So for 2 days I busied myself with wild theories, such as that it had something to do with serving static files (understand that I am a noob and noobs don't know what they're doing).

So what was it? It is now Mr. Moderator that we come to a useful tip. Whereas my development Django is version 1.5.something, my production server version is 1.5.something+1... or maybe plus 2. Whatever. And so after I added the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to the desktop version of *settings.py*, which lacked what hwjp requested--- a "default value in settings.py, perhaps with an explanatory comment"--- I did the same on the production server with the proper domain for it.

But I failed to notice that on the production server with the later version of Django there WAS a default value in settings.py with an explanatory comment. It was well below where I made my entry, out of sight on the monitor. And of course the list was empty. Hence my waste of time.

Comment: i had exactly the same hilarious pattern !, except that it became hilarious only after I found this, thanks. before that it was just plain frustrating

Comment: Something that helps in all this is to use a `local_settings.py` for each environment and then import it in `settings.py`.

Comment: what i like to do, is have a settings/ *directory* instead of a settings.py. In this directory, you can have separate .py files for different environments, and a base.py for general settings. Production dependant settings can then start by importing * from the base settings, and just override whatever they need to override. Also, the required __init__.py needed to turn that settings/ directory into a valid module, can first import from base.py, and then try to import from a local.py (which would only exist locally). that would mean you don't need to specify local settings manually

Answer (score 7):

ALLOWED_HOSTS is NOT the only issue, for me I had to make a 404.html and put it in the base level of my templates (not app level) - Also, you can make a 404 view and add a 404handler url but I think thats optional. 404.html fixed it

in mainproject.urls

```
handler404 = 'app.views.custom_404'
```

in app.views

```
def custom_404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', {}, status=404)
```

then make a templates/404.html template

got this from another S/O post that I cannot find it

**EDIT**

also, I get 500 errors when I serve assets with whitenoise. Could not figure that out for the life of me, error was ValueError from whitenoise not being able to find an asset that I also could not find, had to go with default django serving for now

Comment: I had the same problem with whitenoise. `python manage.py collectstatic` fixed it.

Comment: @amchungh89 you are a life saver! Thanx for pointing that out.

Comment: handler404 also fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is a super old question, but maybe I could help some one else.  If you are having a 500 error after setting DEBUG=False, you can always run the manage.py runserver in the command line to see any errors that wont appear in any web error logs.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem when I did `DEBUG = FALSE`. Here is a consolidated solution as scattered in answers above and other posts.

By default, in settings.py we have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` . Here are possible changes you will have to make in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` value as per scenario to get rid of the error:

1: Your domain name:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com'] # Your domain name here
```

2: Your deployed server IP if you don't have domain name yet (which was my case and worked like a charm):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['123.123.198.123'] # Enter your IP here
```

3: If you are testing on local server, you can edit your `settings.py` or `settings_local.py` as:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

4: You can also provide '*' in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` value but its **not recommended in the production environment** due to security reasons:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # Not recommended in production environment
```

I have also posted a detailed solution on my [blog](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/01/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error-solved.html) which you may want to refer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is quite old but it's still perfectly relevant today.

For what it's worth - I was getting a 500 with `DEBUG = False` for all pages on my site.

I got no traceback when in debug.

I had to go through every static link in my templates within my site and found one / (forward slash) in front of my image source. {% static ... %}. This caused the 500 error in `DEBUG = False` but worked perfectly fine in `Debug = True` with no errors. Very annoying! Be warned! Many hours of time wasted due to a forward slash...

Comment: Wow! thanks for saving time. I had a static tag pointing to non existing file and was throwing 500 on `Debug=False`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to run `python manage.py collectstatic` after you set `DEBUG = False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']` in `settings.py`. After these two steps my web application ran well in my local server even with DEBUG=False mode.

BTW I have these settings in `settings.py`.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # what i added
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', # and so on...
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I assume maybe whitenoise setting has something to do with collectstatic command.

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar issue, in my case it was caused by having a Commented script inside the body tag.

```
<!--<script>  </script>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it could also be the http server settings. Mine is still broken and had ALLOWED_HOSTS the entire time. I can access it locally (i use gunicorn), but not via the domain name when DEBUG=False. when I try using the domain name it then gives me the error, so makes me think its a nginx related issue.

Here is my conf file for nginx:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name localhost myproject.ca www.myproject.ca;
    root /var/web/myproject/deli_cms;

    # serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
    location /media/ {
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location /admin/media/ {
        # this changes depending on your python version
        root /var/web/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib;
    }
    location /static/ {
    alias /var/web/myproject/deli_cms/static_root/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Comment: my gunicorn config file is as follows: 
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/web/delicms_env/deli_cms/
source ../bin/activate
exec gunicorn --workers=3 deli_cms.wsgi:application

Comment: my problem is now solved, I was using the gunicorn_django script and it was giving me deprecated messages. Still not sure why it worked locally, didn't change my nginx config just changed the old script to use gunicorn and use the wsgi:application module instead and it works again. Gunicorn was throwing some deprecation messages before this as well but nothing specific to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, and off course there could be a legion of issues but I've had a similar issue and it turned out that I had {% %} special characters inside my html remark...

```
<!-- <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue. Turns out I was including in the template, using the `static` template tag, a file that did not exist anymore. A look in the logs showed me the problem.

I guess this is just one of many possible reasons for this kind of error.

Moral of the story: always log errors and always check logs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @squarebear, in the log file, I found the error:
`ValueError: The file 'myapp/styles.css' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage ...>`.

I had a few problems in my django app. I removed the line
 `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'` which I found from the heroku's documentation.

I also had to add extra directory (thanks to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232706/6210807)) `static` in the root of django application as `myapp/static` even though I wasn't using it. Then running the command `python manage.py collectstatic` before running the server solved the problem. Finally, it started working fine.

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Answer (score 1):

this maybe help someone else, in my case the problem with the missing favicon.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was also getting a 500 error when DEBUG=False. After several hours, I realized I had forgot to end some of the links in my base.html with a trailing slash.

Comment: even the css and js stuff?

Answer (score 0):

This is old and my problem ended up being related to the problem but not for the OP but my solution is for anyone else who tried the above to no avail.

I had a setting in a modified version of Django to minify CSS and JS files that only ran when DEBUG was off. My server did not have the CSS minifier installed and threw the error. If you are using Django-Mako-Plus, this might be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

One small thing to note, If the array has None in it, then all the subsequent allowed hosts are ignored.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "localhost",
    None,
    'example.com', # First DNS alias (set up in the app)
    #'www.example.com', # Second DNS alias (set up in the app)
]
```

`Django version 1.8.4`

Answer (score 0):

I had one view that threw a 500 error in debug=false but worked in debug=true. For anyone who is getting this kind of thing and Allowed Hosts is not the problem, I fixed my view by updating a template's static tag that was pointing to the wrong location.

So I'd suggest just checking links and tags are airtight in any templates used, maybe certain things slip through the net in debug but give errors in production.

Answer (score 0):

I found yet another cause of the 500 error when DEBUG=False.  I use the Django `compressor` utility and our front-end engineer added references to font files *inside* a `compress css` block in a Django template.  Like this:

```
{% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap-spinedit.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "djangular/css/styles.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endcompress %}
```

The solution was to move the link to the `ttf` file below the `endcompress` line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this and I will report how I solved mine because it could be that someone is also experiencing the same.

In my case, the error was caused because the server was not finding some static files from the homepage.

So make sure the error only occurs in the `index` or occurs on another page. If the problem is only occurring in the index very probably you need to check the static files. I recommend opening the Chrome preview console and checking for any errors.

In my case, the server couldn't find `favicon.ico` and two other CSS.

To fix this I passed `python manage.py collectstatic` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get the 500 for debug=False in the form of

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found.
or...
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'about' not found.
```

when raising **django.core.exceptions.ValidationError** instead of raising **rest_framework.serializers.ValidationError**

To be fair, it was already raising a 500 before, but as a ValidationError, with debug=False, this changed into the NoReverseMatch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by removing this line:
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage

Answer (score -1):

my problem was in wrong 404.html template - I copy&pasted

```
<a href="{% url 'home:index' %}">
```

instead of (in my case)

```
 <a href="{% url 'posts:index' %}">
```

that's why 500 apperar

Answer (score -5):

Ok after trying soo many things, the correct solution is ...

you need to set `DEBUG = 'FALSE'` not `False` or `FALSE`, but `'FALSE'` with `''`

Comment: I think 'FALSE' is a string, so it's equal to True, that's why it does not get an error.

Answer (score -7):

If you want to allow for all hosts. 
Use ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',] 
instead of 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']