# variables included in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS not in template with DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When I set `DEBUG=False` in my settings file in django 1.5, I no longer have access to the `STATIC_URL` or any of the other variables that should be loaded by my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in my django templates. Oddly, everything works when `DEBUG=True`. For what its worth, I definitely have `'django.core.context_processors.static'` in my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` so that is not the issue. I have also checked a few other variables in my template context and none of the other  nothing seems to be there. `MEDIA_URL`? nope. `request`? nope. [See this example on github](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/django-problem-gist) (which has been updated with solution), but these are the important pieces that correctly work when `DEBUG=True` and throw a 500 error when `DEBUG=False`:

```
# settings.py
from django.conf.global_settings import *
# ...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
# believe it or not, 'django.core.context_processors.static' is in there
print TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 

# views.py
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def wtf(request):
    return render_to_response(
        "wtf.html", {}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Does something special happen in django 1.5 when you turn off debug mode? Any suggestions for fixing and/or debugging the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by editing the [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS) variable in your settings.py. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error) for more details.

To get this to [work on localhost](http://getluky.net/2013/02/21/django-debugfalse-and-allowed_hosts/), for example, set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a change between Django 1.2 and 1.3.

You now have to include `django.core.context_processors.static` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` if you want the `STATIC_URL` available to your template outside of debug mode.

You also need to ensure you're using a `RequestContext` instance when rendering the template.

Comment: thanks for the response, Aya. I clarified the question to make it clear that I am already using the RequestContext and that the django.core.context_processors.static is already in the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Anyway, this doesn't explain why *none* of the other variables are present either. Any ideas?