# Why does setting debug to false in django settings stop Heroku app from loading in development and production?

Tags: django, heroku

In my settings i have set `DEBUG=False` but this instead generated a 500 Error in both dev and production. so i looked around and came across this ([Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)) and tried it out.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.heroku.com']
```

But this did not work, what am i not doing right? Am hosting with heroku

Answer (score 16):

Your app is not hosted on www.heroku.com. Instead, try

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".herokuapp.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
python manage.py collecstatic
```

?

you should review files directory becuase in prodhuction static files directory changes. heroku uses whitenouse