# Django & Heroku: Import error on installed app only when DEBUG=False & on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I recently installed django-notification-1, [see code here if necessary](https://github.com/arctelix/django-notification-1).  When I run my app on my local development server with DEBUG=True or DEBUG=False everything works fine. On heroku with DEBUG=True everything is fine, but when DEBUG=False i get an import error with module 'notification" does not exist.

This is the models.py file within my core app where the import error occurs.  The only thing i use this file for is handling signals and notifications from all the other apps.  I have truncated the file after the first def:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from follow.signals import followed
from django.contrib.comments.signals import comment_was_posted, comment_was_flagged

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template import Context

from notification import models as notification


@receiver(followed, sender=User, dispatch_uid='follow.user')
def user_follow_handler(user, target, instance, **kwargs):

    if user != target:
        notification.send([target], "followed", {"from_user": user}, sender=user)
```

The import fails on the following line:

```
from notification import models as notification
```

I have temporarily fixed it by putting the import inside the function and then it works even with DEBUG=False:

```
@receiver(followed, sender=User, dispatch_uid='follow.user')
def user_follow_handler(user, target, instance, **kwargs):
    from notification import models as notification 
    if user != target:
        notification.send([target], "followed", {"from_user": user}, sender=user)
```

Clearly the import is being called before the the notification app is loaded. But why is it an issue only on heroku with DEBUG=False.  If i set DEBUG=True on heroku everything works and either way it works with models.py runserver.

The question is: What would cause the import behavior to change based on the state of DEBUG on heroku and not my dev server?  And more importantly why would DEBUG ever have an affect on this?

Comment: What's the actual exception thrown?

Comment: you resolved this? also getting the same error.

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218446/why-does-setting-debug-to-false-in-django-settings-stop-app-from-loading-in-devl

Comment: i'm not sure if that's the same issue, but i'll give it a shot...