# Is ALLOWED_HOSTS needed on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, security, heroku, web

From what I understand, `ALLOWED_HOSTS` does a check when `DEBUG=False` to prevent an attacker from pointing their own domain to your site.

It looks like Heroku's [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) do the same thing.

So instead of adding a required `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable in your `app.json` for the [Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) (since it feels redundant and is error-prone when you're in a hurry), can you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` and allow Heroku to verify the requests are coming where they should instead?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218446/why-does-setting-debug-to-false-in-django-settings-stop-app-from-loading-in-devl

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Warning: Possibly Out of Date

The `settings.py` below represents the contents of Heroku's docs when this answer was originally written in 2015. While I am relatively sure the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting presented here is safe, please consult [the up-to-date docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) before copying any of the rest of these settings!

Original answer follows. See below for more information.

---

This is exactly what you are supposed to do, per [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings):

## settings.py

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static asset configuration
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

---

## 2018 Update

The link above no longer works, as Heroku formats their Getting Started docs a bit differently these days, providing pre-built example repos rather than code samples in the docs. The current [Python Getting Started Repo](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/gettingstarted/settings.py#L30) has `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`, but also `DEBUG = True`, which according to [the Django 2.1 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) triggers a special case where

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```

Since `DEBUG = True` is **not recommended or a good idea at all** in production, the original recommendation in this answer still stands as a production-ready solution for a Heroku app. Be sure you read and understand [Charlie Weems' brief answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49374520/2588818) before deciding what to do.

Full Disclosure: I have not built a production Heroku app in a recent version of Django. YMMV :)

Comment: Oh nice! All the tutorials I read had you setting it to `yourapp.herokuapp.com`. Guess I should've gone straight to the docs instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

Note that Heroku [removed](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/commit/180cbfb1d26dd4bf66248ad385d5134ff07126d0) `['*']` from the getting started guide in December 2017.

I recommend setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']`.

Even though Heroku's domain service is providing this protection, specifying the setting will be a reminder to update the configuration if moved to another hosting service.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect out-of-date docs as well as reference yours. Cheers!