# Is there any other solution to set debug=false and make django project ready for production?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I'm developing one simple website that is for company profile along with products/service descriptions and blogs in `Django==2.0.6` with python==3.7  and the database is Postgres. The development is finished and I was trying to host on the Heroku and succeed. But as it is not good practice to keep `DEBUG=True` for the production so I have set `DEGUG=False` and also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost', '127.0.0.1']` to test it locally but it returns `Server Error (500)`.

I have tried to run on Django server and also on the Heroku by hosting it and at both servers, it works perfectly if `DEBUG=True`. I was searching on the internet but all the answers/solution said "to set `DEBUG=False`, `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` for any hosts but which is not recommended for production or `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['www.example.com','.example.com']` but any of this does not work on the Heroku or on Local.

```
"""
Django settings for FactOneTech project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
import django_heroku

AdminSite.site_header = "Fact One Tech Administration"

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<my super secret key>'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'blogs',
    'product',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'FactOneTech.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'FactOneTech/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'home.context_processors.footer_context'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'FactOneTech.wsgi.application'
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'factonetech',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "FactOneTech/static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I expect the solution to run my website with `DEBUG=False`

Comment: Check logs and see why you get 500 error

Comment: log does not contains any error information `2018-12-25T08:13:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-12-25T08:13:38.721481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=factonetech.herokuapp.com request_id=1bc73afd-77b8-4cac-abda-50b90f6af49c fwd="49.34.153.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=338ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
2018-12-25T08:13:38.722591+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.250.60 - - [25/Dec/2018:08:13:38 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "https://factonetech.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/" "User Agent here"`

Comment: You are checking a web log. I was talking about your backend log. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/

Comment: [You need to update your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685688/is-allowed-hosts-needed-on-heroku/49374520#49374520): ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '.herokuapp.com' ]

Comment: Changing `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '.herokuapp.com' ]` is still not working I have tried, is there may be other problems