# Django CMS installation: no welcome page and 500 server error

Tags: django, django-cms

I have istalled Django CMS with http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/tutorial.html
But at the point 1.3.4. Up and running!  -  i don't see any welcome page as i should.
Instead, i still see

**It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Here's what to do next:
    If you plan to use a database, edit the DATABASES setting in pyizbirkom/settings.py.
    Start your first app by running python manage.py startapp [appname].
You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!**

If i set DEBUG = True   to False i see **Server error (500)**  on white page

What should i do?

Update: what i see in console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:35] "GET /static/cms/jstree/tree_component.js HTTP/1.1" 500 5
9
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    return self.serve(request)
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:35] "GET /static/cms/js/libs/jquery.ui.dialog.js HTTP/1.1" 50
0 59
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:35] "GET /static/cms/js/libs/jquery.functional.js HTTP/1.1" 5
00 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:35] "GET /static/cms/js/libs/classy.min.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:35] "GET /static/cms/js/plugins/cms.setup.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:36] "GET /static/cms/js/plugins/cms.base.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
[12/Jun/2013 21:22:36] "GET /static/cms/js/change_list.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 8
5, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\ha
ndlers\wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib
\staticfiles\views.py", line 44, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\s
tatic.py", line 61, in serve
    mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 294, in
guess_type
    init()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in
init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in
read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in
enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the url you set up in `urls.py` (step 1.2)?

Comment: so actually you did everything between `1.2` and `1.3.4`?

Comment: @J. Ghyllebert  my mistake, i have added urlpatterns  before already generated by Django. Then i was able to seewelcome page and login as admin. but address is http://127.0.0.1:8000/en - so docs's mistake. Also i dont see any images and seemed that css is not loaded. All admin panel is white with no formatting

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo  - yes, i run python manage.py cms check - it respond install success. Why not to do web GUI installer like Drupal - i think Django loose a lot of newcomers because of strange and complicated install

Comment: and when i set DEBUG = True to False i see Server error (500)  - this is not changed

Comment: @VicNicethemer try running `manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: @VicNicethemer i think Django looses a lot of newcomers because they don't take enough time to dig in it and expect a "push-the-button-and-it-works" approach. When you see that `500` error, what do you see in your terminal?

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo  update post above with console

Comment: @J. Ghyllebert done, but it respond that 375 files are not updated. So i think it's up to date

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)` and that's your real problem... :/ check for non ordinary chars around...

Comment: do you have a 404.html ???

Comment: @armonge yes, i have created if from renamed base.html - not works

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error). You'll see that you should set your ALLOWED_HOSTS properly in your settings.py file, and if you are trying to view it outside of localhost you'll have to configure Apache (and [mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)) as well.

Comment: I saw that answer, added ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost'] - still 500 error