# Django renders the template `500.html` instead of `404.html`

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

In one of my views I have the code:

```
raise Http404
```

When `DEBUG=False` Django renders the template `500.html` instead of the correct `404.html`! I can't understand why!

EDIT: When `DEBUG=True` I get the standard one (by Django)

```
Page not Found (404)
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

What's more is that in the `runserver` console I see clearly the `404` code. **Instead**, when setting `DEBUG=False` in the console I get a `500`!! This is so odd.

EDIT 2: If I place a print statement just before raising `Http404` I see the message when `DEBUG=True` but not when it is `False`!

EDIT 3: I can confirm that when `DEBUG=False` the statement `raise Http404` is never reached. How can it be possible??

## Update

Actually with `DEBUG=False` at every URL I get a 500. While with `DEBUG=True` this does not happen. How can it possibly be?? It should run the same. I'm starting to think it is a Django bug.

Comment: One raison may be because your 400.html template generates a 500 error, can you post your template ?

Comment: And what happens with DEBUG=True ?

Comment: @maazza: I doubt it. I created a new 404.html and wrote in it just 404. Yet, it didn't get rendered.

Comment: You probably dont have your 404.html in the right place ?

Comment: @karthikr: I have it at the root of my templates directory, as the Django docs say. Proof of this is that if I call: `loader.render_to_string('404.html')` I see the right code.

Comment: your error with debug=false may be due to the allowed_hosts setting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error

Comment: Wow, it works. I really hadn't see that. Thank you so much. Would you add that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error with debug=false may be due to the allowed_hosts setting.

see : [Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/django-setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)

It is new in django 1.5

> ALLOWED_HOSTS required in production
>
> The new ALLOWED_HOSTS setting validates the request’s Host header and
>   protects against host-poisoning attacks. This setting is now required
>   whenever DEBUG is False, or else django.http.HttpRequest.get_host()
>   will raise SuspiciousOperation. For more details see the full
>   documentation for the new setting.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#allowed-hosts-required-in-production

Comment: I have the error but not in all pages, there is only exists on pages with http404 raised error