# Porting Django model to OpenShift

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have a model which I'm keen to integrate to my open shift platform. The issue I'm having is that my view imports the model, but this causes a failure, but this should be pretty standard. I cannot see what the error from the log is - but I don't get any rendering of anything on screen, 500 error.

1. `rhc tail amycoolapp` doesn't provide much guidance to error? Where can I find more errors the rhc tail simply shows the `python.log` - is there another log that I can use that contains more information?
2. `from django.db import models` works when included in `models.py` which in turn is included in `views.py`.
3. Including a class definition causes the failure (
   `class Test(models.Model):
   s="hello"`). It seems the use of models.Model is an issue.
4. My directory structure is such that `models.py` and `views.py` at at the same level in a directory under the app name.
5. In `settings.py` we have: `INSTALLED_APPS = ('amycoolapp',)` which is the name of the app and the folder that `views.py` and `models.py` sits in.
6. Managed to get some logging out: [Wed Jul 30 14:23:30 2014] [error] [client 127.8.250.1] ImportError: No module named 'amycoolapp'

I switched on logging so I get the following when I include the dummy model class in my views.py

```
IndexError at /
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxx.rhcloud.com/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: /var/lib/openshift/53b536da5004463b6e00022e/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py3.3.egg/django/db/models/base.py in __new__, line 92
Python Executable:  /var/lib/openshift/53b536da5004463b6e00022e/python//virtenv/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.3.2
```

Any suggestions? It fails with the addition of:

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    s = 'hello'
```

Comment: Do you have this ( ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*] ) in your setting.py ?

Comment: @alirezasanaee what would this do?

Comment: OpenShift django projects are somewhat tricky. Did you move just an application to a brand new django project in openshift or did you move your entire project?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I have a django app and I'm piece my piece building it up to run in OpenShift.

Comment: So it's the exact clone? I ask it because the django project generated by the django cartridge has not the same structure than a normal django project. There are many times when the openshift version expects the app to be in another directory.

Comment: @Navonod see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/setting-debug-false-causes-500-error