# ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.ico'

Tags: python, django, static, django-views, django-staticfiles

I'm getting a `ValueError` when running `python manage.py test`. My project is named `fellow_go`, and I'm currently working on an App called `pickup`.

Please note that this error is added in a relatively recent commit to Django: [Fixed #24452 -- Fixed HashedFilesMixin correctness with nested paths.](https://github.com/django/django/commit/53bffe8d03f01bd3214a5404998cb965fb28cd0b).

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location (pickup.tests.test_view.HomePageViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/fellow_go/pickup/tests/test_view.py", line 10, in test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location
    resp = self.client.get('/', follow=True)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 536, in get
    **extra)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 340, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 501, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 105, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 102, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 117, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 162, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 141, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 432, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.ico'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> fellow_go/settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# ......

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

> fellow_go/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^pickup/', include('pickup.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    prefix_default_language=False
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> fellow_go/pickup/views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'index.html'
```

> fellow_go/templates/index.html

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}">
```

> fellow_go/pickup/tests/test_view.py

```
class HomePageViewTest(TestCase):

    def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
        resp = self.client.get('/', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Any I do have a `favicon.ico` file:

[image]

---

Strangely, no errors occur with `python manage.py runserver`:

```
/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/bin/python3.6 /Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/fellow_go/manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2017 - 22:09:25
Django version 1.11.1, using settings 'fellow_go.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6276
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2474
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css HTTP/1.1" 200 430
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 200 685
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/js/opt-in.js HTTP/1.1" 200 511
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/css/datetimepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12351
[24/May/2017 22:09:28] "GET /static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 55741
[24/May/2017 22:09:35] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 766
Not Found: /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[24/May/2017 22:09:35] "GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2678
Not Found: /apple-touch-icon.png
[24/May/2017 22:09:35] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2642
```

---

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try running:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Does the test work now? If so, this might be the configuration causing a problem:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

as of whitenoise v4 this will fail and you should use:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32347324/2596187

Check out the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict

Comment: I found this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009055/django-model-valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for-file-name-ext

Comment: Run "python manage.py collecstatic" (again) and refresh the website, should work.

Comment: Just to complement @emazzotta 's answer. I had to run `heroku run python3 manage.py collectstatic` and it worked for me.

Comment: this option was removed in whitenoise v4 http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0 please advise on how to fix the issue using v4

Comment: The OP takes care to point out that they "do have a `favicon.ico` file," but here is a reminder to double-check that the file is where it's supposed to be before re-running `collectstatic.` I somehow bungled the file transfer process during deployment such that the favicon file was left behind, while all the other images were where they should be. The site ran fine with `DEBUG` set to `True` but broke with debugging disabled, with the same error the OP got. Re-running `collectstatic` didn't help till the favicon got put in the static dir, as specified in settings.

Comment: Using Whitenoise 6.6.0, I had to add an explicit `./manage.py collectstatic` call to get our Django-based tests working in CI, before the `./manage.py test` call. With this in place, it works nicely now.

Answer (score 56):

Just sharing the solution I had to this issue in case it helps anyone else.

I was accidentally including the leading "/" in some static URLs which caused them to be missing from the manifest.

The solution was to replace all instances of:

`{% static '/path/to/some/file' %}`

with

`{% static 'path/to/some/file' %}`

and then everything worked properly.

Comment: Can't believe the backend can broke because of this. After endless days with whitenoise configs. You sir just won the internet.

Comment: So annoying that Django can't properly handle it!

Comment: Nice, would not have though of that in a million years haha - Not for future reader only had this issue after setting up whitenoise... when I handle the static files in nginx this didn't matter

Comment: This was my issue too. I had to use my IDE's 'global site' search for "{% static '/" to find the faulty static link!

Answer (score 38):

That not necessarily happens with `whitenoise` package. Changing `STATIC_STORAGE` to `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage` will produce the same error while running tests starting with [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict).

That happens because `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` expects `staticfiles.json` to exist and [contain](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py#L420) the file asked. You can confirm this by running `./manage.py collectstatic` and trying again.

You don't generally see this error in development because when `DEBUG == True`, `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` switches to [non-hashed](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py#L123) urls.

To overcome this you've got to make sure that:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

Which is the default.

One way would be to override settings for the test class:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
@override_settings(STATICFILES_STORAGE='django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage')
class MyTest(TestCase):
    pass
```

or the method:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
class MyTest(TestCase):
    @override_settings(STATICFILES_STORAGE='django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage')
    def test_something(self):
        pass
```

Comment: In my case, simply running `python collectstatic` took care of the issue I was seeing locally. Doh.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to continue to use the [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) module in your Django 1.11 (or newer) project while preventing this "Missing staticfiles manifest entry" error, you need to disable the `manifest_strict` attribute by means of inheritance, as noted in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict).

How to accomplish that?

Firstly, create a `storage.py` file in your project directory:

```
from whitenoise.storage import CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage


class WhiteNoiseStaticFilesStorage(CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage):
    manifest_strict = False
```

Secondly, edit the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` constant in your `settings.py` file to point to this new class, such as:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'my_project.storage.WhiteNoiseStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: This is now a setting you can use directly in your whitenoise config, instead of having to extend the class http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html?highlight=manifest_strict#WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT

Answer (score 10):

Django raises this exception if you reference a static file during your tests, but you haven't run `./manage.py collectstatic` since creating that file ([see these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict)).

The recommended way to resolve this is:

> During testing, ensure that the STATICFILES_STORAGE setting is set to something else like 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage' (the default).

Here's a simple way to do that in your `settings.py`:

```
import sys

TESTING = len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
    if TESTING
    else 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
)
```

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of Whitenoise (currently 5.2) you can now do..

```
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False
```

Comment: Saw this in the Whitenoise docs too, but did not work for me. To test this, intentionally reference a missing file while using `whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage`. For me, running `Django==3.1.2` and the same version of Whitenoise you mentioned, the error still persists.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue; where I was getting "Missing static files manifest entry for" every time I ran my server with DEBUG = False.

It took me many hours to figure out that the problem was with including "/" at the start of my static links.

For example:
{% static '/app/styles/main.css' %} instead of {% static 'app/styles/main.css' %}

Answer (score 2):

An actual solution can be found [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#why-do-i-get-valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for)

The problem is that Django doesn't actually knows where the static file is and when you do
`python manage.py collectstatic` it actually doesn't copy it to you're `STATIC_ROOT`

Solution

1. manually try to find you're static files using
   `python manage.py findstatic <your static files>`

   you need to do this for every static files. if this command didn't work that means Django can't find your static files. In order to fix that problem you need to define the static files path inside your
   `STATIC_DIRS` inside your settings.py

example

```py
STATIC_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path/to/your/staticfiles")
]
```

2. define

```py
STATIC_ROOT = "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

3. do `python manage.py collectstatic`
   and after that it should be working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer saved me. When I reverted my commit, my staticfiles/admin folder was removed somehow, and I had never manually removed it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed by changing `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'
```

Then you should run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 1):

i have this in my setting.py

```
DEBUG = False
try:
    from .local_setting import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

after I removed the try block, everything work again.

Comment: Only `DEBUG=False`, related to this problem, if you set it to `DEBUG=True`, you'll achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466192/server-error-500-django-deployment-on-heroku?noredirect=1&lq=1) helped my solve this problem.

First add this in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': ('%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] '
                   'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s '
                   'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}}
```

And then add this at end of your settings.py, if you are using django-heroku:

```
django_heroku.settings(config=locals(), staticfiles=False,logging=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was occurring because I am using nginx (Docker) to serve the static images.  This is occurring when the app is running, not during testing like the OP.

The issue was that I was declaring the `STATIC_ROOT` to be outside of the Django app:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "../staticfiles"
```

I did this so that the assets were not unnecessarily copied onto the Django container.  This works fine if you use the default [`STATICFILES_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-storage), but when using `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`, the static file lookup fails because it cannot find manifest file asset in directory on the Django container.

The solution is simply to declare static files to be present on the Django image:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "staticfiles"
```

This does create to copies of the static files: one copy on the nginx container, and one on Django, but it means that the Django lookup logic succeeds, even though the files are served from nginx.

Another option would be to disable the [`manifest_strict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict) attribute:

> storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict
>
> If a file isn’t found in the staticfiles.json manifest at runtime, a
> ValueError is raised. This behavior can be disabled by subclassing
> ManifestStaticFilesStorage and setting the manifest_strict attribute to
> False – nonexistent paths will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

env: **Python 3.8, Django 3.1.5**

Basically i don't use whitenoise. In my opinion Django's [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) class do the great job in collect staticfiles. It add unique hash, works fast and don't need any other dependencies.

On production serwer (where staticfiles are served by nginx from 'public' folder) my staticfiles settings looks like below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public', 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

and that's all. With this configuration after run `python manage.py collectstatic` Django will get all files from `static` folder and move it into `public`. It will also create copy of each file with unique id and will create `staticfiles.json` which contain all staticfiles map with original static files names and its "hashed" version, e.g.

```
{... "css/main.css": "css/main.31cdb680414e.css", main.js": "main.b08f762abac7.js"...}
```

With this approach if you use in your template: `{% static 'images/my-image.jpg' %}` it will be converted into `path_to_image/my-image.828172380.jpg`
What is quite convinience especially if you change something in your css or js files and want to apply changes to all without necessity of clearing browser cache.

**One important note**
You can face issue described here "Missing staticfiles manifest for... " if you will add staticfiles with slash at the beginning. So in your template:

**This will work**

```
<div class="slide slide1" style="background-image: url('{% static 'images/slider/129557309.jpg' %}');">
```

**This is wrong and won't work, you will have exception**

```
<div class="slide slide1" style="background-image: url('{% static '/images/slider/129557309.jpg' %}');">
```

It's small difference but you have to remember it. Hope it will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not sure why it happens, but after I removed the `heroku` settings `django_heroku.settings(locals())` everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that, in one place, I was referring to a folder, images, as `{% static 'images' %}`. Changing that to `{% static 'images/' %}`, with a slash at the end, solved the problem. Mind-boggling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer for those using Whitenoise along with Django >= 4.2:

```py
# settings.py
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage",
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
        if not TESTING
        else "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage",
        # disables the caching behavior for the tests, for static files to load properly
    },
}
```

This new `STORAGES` setting is mentioned in [this release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#custom-file-storages) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-STORAGES) in the Django documentation.

Whitenoise documentation has also been updated as you can see [here](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django.html#add-compression-and-caching-support).

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. I am running Django 4.2.6 and whitenoise 6.6.9

Comment: Still working well for me with the same config ;) Your issue probably stems from something else!