# Missing staticfiles manifest entry while rendering template in Django TestCases

Tags: django, nose, django-testing, django-tests, collectstatic

I'm running into a problem with running `TestCase`s in which I am rendering the template of a page in order to test pieces of the HTML that are produced.

Here is an example of the kind of test I am running:

**test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

class NavTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_standard_user_nav(self):
        self.client.login(username='username', password='password')
        user = auth.get_user(self.client)
        response = self.client.get('/')
        content = response.render().content
        # Run logic to check pieces of the nav in the rendered HTML
```

***requirements.txt***

```
django-material==1.0.0
django-nose==1.4.5
nose==1.3.7
```

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

The issue is with code I added into my `base.html` file to support using [django-material](http://forms.viewflow.io/) for a recent redesign of the site.  Below, the three lines in `<head>` are copied directly from the `django-material` documentation.

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    {% include 'material/includes/material_css.html' %}
    <script src="{% static '[material/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    {% include 'material/includes/material_js.html' %}
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

For reference, here are links to those files:

- https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/master/material/templates/material/includes/material_css.html
- https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/tree/master/material/static/material/js
- https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/master/material/templates/material/includes/material_js.html

However, these lines are what are breaking my tests.  I am getting these two errors:

- `WARNING Exception raised while rendering {% include %} ... ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'material/fonts/material-design-icons/material-icons.css'` ==> This is the first call in material_css.html.
- `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'material/js/jquery.js'`  ==> This is the 2nd line in base.html specific by the django-material docs.

<del>I do not have this problem with any other static files, either those created by me (whose entries I left out of the trimmed-down base.html I pasted above) or even seemingly the other ones provided by `django-material`.</del>  Actually, on closer inspection, when I remove these three lines, it then breaks on the subsequent calls to 'static' (which, again, I omitted from this example for simplicity).

Now, following the advice of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160666/valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for-favicon-ico), when I run `collectstatic` locally, it does take care of this problem.  However, when I deploy the code and run the tests remotely, I don't know how to get `collectstatic` to run there.  I tried changing the base class of my tests to [StaticLiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#specialized-test-case-to-support-live-testing), but that did not make a difference.  I also see from the [Nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_tests/test_init_plugin/init_plugin.html) that I could create a `setUp()` routine in my testing class, but given that I run tests like this in many test classes all over my code, I want to avoid running `collectstatic` multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a feature and not a bug.  I had to change how I did deployments to run `collectstatic` before running the tests -- this required a change in the .yml config file custom to my continuous integration environment -- totally unrelated to any of the above.  D'oh.