# Server error (500) Django deployment on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-settings, server-error

I turned debug to False in my settings.py file (note that before I turned it to false, everything was workign perfectly) and when I ran `git push heroku master` and went to my website, the home page was working but that wasn't the case for all of my pages: on some, I got an error saying `Server Error (500)`

Here is my `settings.py` code :

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["hacka-labs.herokuapp.com"]
```

What I have noticed is that the urls where I pass an id aren't working

Please help me if you know the answer

Comment: maybe some pages need to static files or want to read data from db, and you don't have permission to access them

Comment: I think this isn't the problem because everything was working perfectly before I turned DEBUG to False.

Comment: did you define static route in urls.py file?

Comment: No. Do I really have to ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it's hard to figure out when DEBUG is set to False. When I reconfigured it back to `DEBUG = True` everything worked fine again. So the problem was

> You don't generally see this error in development because when `DEBUG = True`, ManifestStaticFilesStorage switches to non-hashed urls.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060143/7986808

The solution to the problem in your case may differ from mine. But you can find the problem by changing the logging method of your Django project, so you can see more info in the command line when running `heroku logs -t -a <heroku-app>` even in `DEBUG = False` mode.

Change your django logging settings in `settings.py` as follow:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': ('%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] '
                       'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s '
                       'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Then run `heroku logs -t -a <heroku-app>` and open the url where you previously got 500 Error you will find out the problem in logs. Hope this will help you.

---

In case there are some static files missing just switch your static root in `settings.py` as follow `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`. Running `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic -a <heroku-app>` creates staticfiles directory.

Comment: Also need to add `django_heroku.settings(config=locals(), staticfiles=False,logging=False)` logging =False

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I solved issue by removing `import django heroku` in `settings.py`

Comment: `import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())`
Reference:https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while deploying react and django project on heroku.
I had been debugging for 2 days, doing all things like allowed host, staticfiles, json, whitenoise things but that still didn't solve the problem.

If your browswer throws error 500 then set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`. If it throws a TemplateDoesNotExist error at index.html then changing views.py may help solve that. Don't forget to set`DEBUG=False` before deploying.

I solved it by changing some code in views.py.

```
def index(request):

return render(request,'ur_app_name.html')
```

TO

```
def index(request):

some_variable_name=TemplateResponse(request,'ur_app_name.html',{})

return some_variable_name
```

Dont't forgot to import this on top of views.py

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
```

I don't know what exact problem I was facing, I guess it's an httpResponse thing because server needs http request and our local machine does not need it.

Some key points points for this error:

1. Make sure you mention your domain name in `ALLOWED_HOST` in `settings.py` file
2. set `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` `in settings.py`, this maybe needed when heroku throws a
   `collecticstatic` error but I am not sure. If it still throws the
   same error then disable `collectstatic=1` on command (you can find
   the exact command for this in the debug log) which does not create
   any problem.
3. set `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware`, in `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`, this might help.
4. If your project uses react and django then choose python only on add build pack on heroku. Do not choose node.js.

This is the [github repository](https://github.com/ashishadhikary/sentimentUI) where I upload my heroku project you can find the config files here which maybe helpful.

If your project uses react and django and above suggestions didn't help this may help:

- check `.gitignore` files, install all `requirement.txt` files
  and copy `package.json` file in root directory.

set `"build": "cd <project folder name>&& react-scripts build"`, in scripts in `package.json`

My index.html and manifest.json is in the github repo mentioned above.
The 'staticfiles' directory was created in the root folder using '$ `python manage.py collectstatic`'. Try copying my `index.html` file if your project doesn't have one.
That's all.

The herokuapp link :https://sainterface.herokuapp.com/