# django deploy to Heroku : Server Error(500)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku.
Deploy was done correctly but I got Server Error(500).
When I turned DEBUG true, Sever Error doesn't occurred.
So I think there is something wrong with loading staticfiles.

I can't find any notable, critical error in log.
I have already installed whitenoise, but it doesn't work.

Is there anyone who solves this problem?

heroku logs

```
2019-02-26T17:01:26.064554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-02-26T17:01:34.347474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn project5.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-02-26T17:01:37.602081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-26T17:01:37.192553+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-26 17:01:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-02-26T17:01:37.199091+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-26 17:01:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:35760 (4)
2019-02-26T17:01:37.199669+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-26 17:01:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-02-26T17:01:37.219788+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-26 17:01:37 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-02-26T17:01:37.317796+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-26 17:01:37 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-02-26T17:01:39.269757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=shunka-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=a5a7c921-c0d2-4bc2-8831-371da12d3945 fwd="111.239.176.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=522ms status=500 bytes=234 protocol=https
2019-02-26T17:01:39.271879+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.220.185 - - [27/Feb/2019:02:01:39 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"
```

settings.py

```py
import os
import dj_database_url
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = False

SECRET_KEY = ***

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog5.apps.Blog5Config',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'markdownx',
    'widget_tweaks',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project5.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project5.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config() }
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

wsgi.py

```py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project5.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn project5.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: have you install gunicorn in heroku ?

Comment: Yes. I set gunicorn==19.9.0 in requirements.txt

Comment: Try this DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1, in settings->reveal configs->add this

Comment: I tried, but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have anything to do with whitenoise. The problem is your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting; this needs to have the hostname of your site.

Comment: I tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], but didn't work.  Is there another way to set ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: Try ALLOWED_HOSTS =[ '.herokuapp.com']

Comment: I tryed ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], ALLOWED_HOSTS =[ '.herokuapp.com'] and ALLOWED_HOSTS=['shunka-blog.herokuapp.com']. But still have server error...

Comment: Same issue here. ['*', '.herokuapp.com'] doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem even when my ALLOWED_HOST settings were correct and DEBUGING = False

But what cause mine was that i did not make migration on my herokuapp after deploying.
I solved it by typing

```
heroku run bash
```

then make migrations with `

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

Your database may not be in sync. This might happen after you reset database.
Run

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

to sync the database.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my app to EC2,  instead of Heroku.
It works well at present when DEBUG is turned False.

So I close this question.
Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Make DEBUG = True in your settings.py file for checking exact error occurred and add heroku domain URL in ALLOWED_HOST list.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little instruction here how I solved this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/56456466/7986808. In short: you need to change the logging to find out the real problem in heroku logs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because the application URL was not inside the `CSRF TRUSTED ORIGINS` list and I just had to add it in my `settings.py` like this:

`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://nameoftheapp.herokuapp.com"]`