# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 24: 'trans'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My question is related to DJANGO application

I´m using **DJANGO 3.1.7**

After developed my code using locale capability **{% trans 'value' %}** tag in the correct order all works fine until I turned **DEBUG = False** in the **settings.py**.The following error shows:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 24: 'trans'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

The application blocked showing the following message in the Screen.

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

In the server the following message has been showed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 130, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 49, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 103, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 142, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\defaults.py", line 88, in server_error
    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\cached.py", line 53, in get_template
    template = super().get_template(template_name, skip)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 472, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 531, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 24: 'trans'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Here are my **settings.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from htmlmin.minify import html_minify


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "CHANGE_ME!!!! (P.S. the SECRET_KEY environment variable will be used, if set, instead)."

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'django.contrib.sites', # using sites for sitemap
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'livereload',
    "pwa",    
    "app",    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",  
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',    
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware", 
    "htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware",
    "htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware",    
]

HTML_MINIFY = True

ROOT_URLCONF = "myapp.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [                
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",                
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ]                      
        },
    }
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "myapp.wsgi.application"

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE" : "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]

# PWA
PWA_APP_DEBUG_MODE = False

PWA_APP_NAME = 'My website'
PWA_APP_DESCRIPTION = "My website description"
PWA_APP_THEME_COLOR = '#07689F'
PWA_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#ffffff'
PWA_APP_DISPLAY = 'standalone'
PWA_APP_SCOPE = '/'
PWA_APP_ORIENTATION = 'any'
PWA_APP_START_URL = '/'
PWA_APP_STATUS_BAR_COLOR = 'default'
PWA_APP_ICONS = [
    {
        'src': '/static/images/mylogo_logo.png',        
        "type": 'image/png',
        "sizes": "512x512"
    }
]
PWA_APP_ICONS_APPLE = [
    {
        'src': '/static/images/mylogo_logo.png',        
        'type': 'image/png',
        "sizes": "512x512"
    }
]
PWA_APP_DIR = 'ltr'
PWA_APP_LANG = 'en-US'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('pt-br', _('Portuguese')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.abspath(BASE_DIR), "app", "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(BASE_DIR), "staticfiles")

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here are a sample of my **base.html** template.

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load pwa %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="{% trans "en" %}">
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title> 
</head>

<body>
</body>
    
</html>
```

In the code are several tags with **{% trans 'value' %}** and all sintax are correct.

Some idea about this issue?

Comment: Are all your tags like `<html lang="{% trans "en" %}">`?  Make sure the have single quotes inside, `<html lang="{% trans 'en' %}">`.

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, @BrianDestura. I included in the description of issue the version tha I´m using. 3.1.7

Comment: Hello @raphael I changed all trans tago quotes to single quote. I re-executed makemessages and compilemessages and error still remain.

Comment: I'm not sure, it looks like you have all the correct settings.  But I don't understand the purpose of `<html lang="{% trans 'en' %}">`.  Do you still get the error if you replace that with just `<html lang="en">`, but continue to use the `trans` in the rest of your templates?

Comment: @raphael I included the trans in lang just to switch between languages base.html enable languages in the HTML (I saw this in some documentation during searching). I removed trans from lang in HTML tag but the error still remain.

Comment: Django 3.1 uses `translate` and not `trans`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag

Comment: Hi @BrianDestura, I have to do some more digging, but according to what I see in the link you added, Django 3.1 still supports `trans` for backwards compatibility (NOT so in Django 4.0).  Which means I have to change my code since I'm using 4.0.  I'm curious, @SpeedJunior, does changing this work, because I'm using Django 4.0 with no issues yet using `trans`.

Comment: Doubt it would help, but did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?  Sorry, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @BrianDestura I changed all my tags from `trans` to `translate`. I executed again the `makemessages -l` command for each language and `compilemessages`. The error still there. And the most stranger thing is that. The most stranger thing is that. I´m not using `trans` tag in all code and the error still related to this.

Comment: @rahael. I executed this command and nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solution that I have found.

1. Once that is switched `DEBUG=False` in the `settings.py`, error pages will be included during the `runserver` process. I the first line of my 404.html template and 500.html template I forgot to include `{% load i18n %}`. I included this and done. The way to identify this was by the suggestion from @BrianDestura that suggest to change `trans` tag to `translate` tha I did. Thanks @BrianDestura.
2. After change it, in the production configuration is necessary to run `python manage.py collectstatic` to update paths. That is intersting because during `Debug` mode all the references were OK. Thanks @raphael for your contribution here.The good reference for missing files I found in ([ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.ico'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160666/valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for-favicon-ico))