# how to fix Heroku error when trying to push -- pre-receive hook declined

Tags: django, heroku

I was trying to push what i have in my app using Django python to be deployed to Heroku and keep getting this error :

```
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-brushlands'
```

requriment.txt file is there :

```
asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.7
cloudinary==1.26.0
cryptography==35.0.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.5
django-bootstrap4==3.0.1
django-braces==1.14.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-oauth-toolkit==1.5.0
django-rest-framework-social-oauth2==1.1.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
jwcrypto==1.0
oauthlib==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.1
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.3.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.26.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.16.0
social-auth-app-django==5.0.0
social-auth-core==4.1.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
stripe==2.59.0
urllib3==1.26.7
whitenoise==5.3.0
wrapt==1.13.2
```

my Procfile in root directory and contain:

```
web : gunicorn foodhub.wsgi
```

I was trying to push what i have in my app using Django python to be deployed to Heroku and keep getting this error :
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-brushlands'`

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.7
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.10.7
-----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting asgiref==3.5.2
         Downloading asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting certifi==2022.9.24
         Downloading certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
       Collecting cloudinary==1.26.0
         Downloading cloudinary-1.26.0.tar.gz (170 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting dj-database-url==1.0.0
         Downloading dj_database_url-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
       Collecting Django==4.1.2
         Downloading Django-4.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
       Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1
         Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       Collecting psycopg2==2.9.4
         Downloading psycopg2-2.9.4.tar.gz (384 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting six==1.16.0
         Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.4.3
         Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting tzdata==2022.4
         Downloading tzdata-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (336 kB)
       Collecting urllib3==1.26.12
         Downloading urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
       Collecting whitenoise==6.2.0
         Downloading whitenoise-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: cloudinary, psycopg2
         Building wheel for cloudinary (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for cloudinary (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for cloudinary: filename=cloudinary-1.26.0-py3-none-any.whl size=134187 sha256=391663ac9f9caa29fca028ee944bf59a6ac5066a9aa1012fb188ff52dac36979
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-odd2a9t_/wheels/58/0d/32/997fc6c26f83c9ae73a1bcd41028973512175982df608523ef
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.4-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=159965 sha256=cae6fb7d596d71258bdd30d91a0aa6ec5e8d5ba26d5c2c8f9601e00eb569ea53
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-odd2a9t_/wheels/10/07/ca/a5e7863aeec605e8a19ea9ccc90bb594784c287cc5534bbecb
       Successfully built cloudinary psycopg2
       Installing collected packages: whitenoise, urllib3, tzdata, sqlparse, six, psycopg2, gunicorn, certifi, asgiref, Django, cloudinary, dj-database-url, django-heroku
       Successfully installed Django-4.1.2 asgiref-3.5.2 certifi-2022.9.24 cloudinary-1.26.0 dj-database-url-1.0.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-20.1.0 psycopg2-2.9.4 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.3 tzdata-2022.4 urllib3-1.26.12 whitenoise-6.2.0
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Post-processing 'js/canvas-to-blob.min.js' failed!
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_b3caaaea/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_b3caaaea/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
           raise processed
       whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'js/canvas-to-blob.min.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff53e881d50>.
       The JS file 'js/canvas-to-blob.min.js' references a file which could not be found:
         js/canvas-to-blob.min.js.map
       Please check the URL references in this JS file, particularly any
       relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
****** Collectstatic environment variables:
       PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
       PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/pkg-config:/app/.heroku/python/lib/pkg-config:
       DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       BPLOG_PREFIX=buildpack.python
       PWD=/tmp/build_b3caaaea
       HOME=/app
       LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       SOURCE_VERSION=495ce7e183efedd2df883a898d49dab71e966050
       REQUEST_ID=9bd57211-cb18-3350-055d-aa2d6bfe888e
       ENV_DIR=/tmp/d20221008-54-7rg3a6
       PYTHONPATH=.
       CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
       BIN_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin
       LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
       SHLVL=1
       LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
       PIP_NO_PYTHON_VERSION_WARNING=1
       BUILDPACK_LOG_FILE=/dev/null
       STACK=heroku-22
       BUILD_DIR=/tmp/build_b3caaaea
       CACHE_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache
       PATH=/app/.heroku/python/bin:/app/.heroku/vendor/bin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/vendor/
       EXPORT_PATH=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin/../export
       C_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
       DYNO=run.5378
       PROFILE_PATH=/tmp/build_b3caaaea/.profile.d/python.sh
       OLDPWD=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136
       _=/usr/bin/env
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
remote:        Collecting tzdata==2022.4
remote:          Downloading tzdata-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (336 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.26.12
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==6.2.0
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: cloudinary, psycopg2
remote:          Building wheel for cloudinary (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for cloudinary (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for cloudinary: filename=cloudinary-1.26.0-py3-none-any.whl size=134187 sha256=a8e60aba890ebec526fa450889f89331a3f91deb0951c91ab9e6cbcf4452cf43
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-nqiyqf0q/wheels/58/0d/32/997fc6c26f83c9ae73a1bcd41028973512175982df608523ef   
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.4-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=159965 sha256=8087037db2c9ec2fdbae93eb5afd833509bbcbdbd546e980794242a06e01b87a
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-nqiyqf0q/wheels/10/07/ca/a5e7863aeec605e8a19ea9ccc90bb594784c287cc5534bbecb   
remote:        Successfully built cloudinary psycopg2
remote:        Installing collected packages: whitenoise, urllib3, tzdata, sqlparse, six, psycopg2, gunicorn, certifi, asgiref, Django, cloudinary, dj-database-url, django-heroku
remote:        Successfully installed Django-4.1.2 asgiref-3.5.2 certifi-2022.9.24 cloudinary-1.26.0 dj-database-url-1.0.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-20.1.0 psycopg2-2.9.4 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.3 tzdata-2022.4 urllib3-1.26.12 whitenoise-6.2.0
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Post-processing 'js/load-image.all.min.js' failed!
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_f2d02e58/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_f2d02e58/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
remote:            raise processed
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'js/load-image.all.min.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f5b6e77dd50>.
remote:        The JS file 'js/load-image.all.min.js' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          js/load-image.all.min.js.map
remote:        Please check the URL references in this JS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:
remote: ****** Collectstatic environment variables:
remote:
remote:        PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
remote:        PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/pkg-config:/app/.heroku/python/lib/pkg-config:
remote:        DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:        BPLOG_PREFIX=buildpack.python
remote:        PWD=/tmp/build_f2d02e58
remote:        HOME=/app
remote:        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
remote:        SOURCE_VERSION=495ce7e183efedd2df883a898d49dab71e966050
remote:        REQUEST_ID=8dbf04e4-d06f-2a07-26fd-fd9f783c0707
remote:        ENV_DIR=/tmp/d20221008-55-86y9b6
remote:        PYTHONPATH=.
remote:        CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
remote:        BIN_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin
remote:        LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
remote:        SHLVL=1
remote:        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
remote:        PIP_NO_PYTHON_VERSION_WARNING=1
remote:        BUILDPACK_LOG_FILE=/dev/null
remote:        STACK=heroku-22
remote:        BUILD_DIR=/tmp/build_f2d02e58
remote:        CACHE_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache
remote:        PATH=/app/.heroku/python/bin:/app/.heroku/vendor/bin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/vendor/
remote:        EXPORT_PATH=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin/../export
remote:        C_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
remote:        DYNO=run.5998
remote:        PROFILE_PATH=/tmp/build_f2d02e58/.profile.d/python.sh
remote:        OLDPWD=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136
remote:        _=/usr/bin/env
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 495ce7e183efedd2df883a898d49dab71e966050
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 495ce7e183efedd2df883a898d49dab71e966050
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to immense-brushlands-83439.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/immense-brushlands-83439.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-brushlands-83439.git'
```

Comment: please post the Heroku log

Comment: hi where can i find it

Comment: 2 ways to find it:
1) when you run git push Heroku, it generates a log in your terminal.
2)You can go to the Heroku dashboard open the application page and look for the release log (should be in the activity tab)

Comment: @Noah i just post it

Comment: Note the error message that your Heroku build printed: `whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'js/canvas-to-blob.min.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7ff53e881d50>.` This is not a Python or Git error (and probably not even django but I left that tag alone): it's just a file you forgot to require or provide or whatever.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Find or provide the file. What does the documentation for this "whitenoise" thing, whatever it may be, say about this?

Comment: i don't have any file like this in my directory i only use python and django

Comment: But you have `whitenoise` as a requirement. You're depending on whitenoise. Whitenoise is apparently depending on something else based on some other input you provided to whitenoise. Looks like you may need to do more homework on this.

Comment: but where i can find this whitenoise in my files or directory ?

Comment: Can you check this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829435/collectstatic-command-fails-when-whitenoise-is-enabled