# Django in production: set DEBUG = False causes `Server Error (500)`

Tags: django, exception, error-handling, django-settings

I know this question [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/setting-debug-false-causes-500-error). But the problem persists, and I am left without any solution. Please help.

My platform is: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Python 3.4, MySQL 5.5, Django 1.7, Nginx 1.4.6, and Gunicorn 19.1.1.

When I set `DEBUG = False` in the production server, my Django application runs OK for maybe half a day. And after that, the annoying `Server Error (500)` always appear for certain functions, but not every one. If I turn `DEBUG = True`, everything will be fine.

I also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`. Some said that it should not be a wild card in production. But my app is for public, how should I set it? Others said that it should be `'localhost'`. But only `localhost` can access the server? Why go production, then?

Is there a standard solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Might not be related to `DUBUG` :) Do you have logging enabled, or configured ADMINS that receive 500 error emails?

Comment: Thanks alecxe. Would you advise how to enable logging? I have logged Nginx and Gunicorn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

500 error on production is not something you should make guesses about.

You need to know exactly what, where and when is it happening:

- enable [Django Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) and log, log, log
- set [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins) configuration setting and receive emails on critical errors

> ADMINS
>
> Default: () (Empty tuple)
>
> A tuple that lists people who get code error notifications. When
>   DEBUG=False and a view raises an exception, Django will email these
>   people with the full exception information.

Other related materials:

- [Getting Started with Django Logging in 5 Minutes](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html)
- "Chapter 24: Logging: What's It For, Anyway?" chapter of ["Two Scoops of Django"](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6)

<sup>I understand that it doesn't provide you with an answer and doesn't directly solve your problem, but I hope you get my point, thanks.</sup>

Comment: OK, I set ADMINS (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins), gmail smtp (http://www.mangooranges.com/2008/09/15/sending-email-via-gmail-in-django/), and logging (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/). Everything works OK now. Will keep on watching. Thanks a million, alexce.