# Django login doesnt work when deployed live

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-login

I've seen this question asked before and not answered, so I'm going to give as much detail as possible. [Django login gives http 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267689/django-login-gives-http-500-error)

Locally both my out the box admin and allauth admin work fine, however deploying to cpanel or aws my app crashes with a server 500 error on "post". However, if I sign in the credentials do make it to the database, but the 500 error is still generated. If the credentials are wrong, django generates the right response. So the post makes it to the endpoint, but not back. For cpanel I used mysql, the connection was fine. I was able to add things from the backend into the app. This time I kept sqlite to see if it was just a database issue, for example not allowing remote connection. Wrong again, for aws I tried to add the wsgipassauth on to the config file. No luck, I'm fairly new to django. I'd think this is a problem many encounter when going live but I don't see much support for it. It's as if the admin urls and all auth urls aren't beings brought in, however if debug is on true I can see the urls are there. The path is admin/login/?next=/admin/

```
#settings.py 
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: can you show the exact error message and stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so the reason this issue doesn't appear much is the problem was my code. The app has different tiers, and subscriptions. Like a mvc for java type, I was blocking my own connect with the free tier. I wish I could provide the traceback, but I hope to never see that error again.