# Django Deploying 500 status when debug=False

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to build my own blog now and I think it's good. But now I've noticed a problem. When I change the `DEBUG` const to `False`, System checks are OK but It'll return a 500 error status. When I change it to `True`,The bug won't happen again. So what's the problem? Can anybody help me?

Comment: '500 status' isn't enough information to tell what the problem is. You need to show the full error message, either from your logs or the error emails send to the site admins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)

Comment: Are you are lacking the 404.html and 500.html error templates? that will raise a 500 error on a 404, paired with some URL rule that is only added on debug. also check your ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py so its not empty.