# Django DEBUG=False getting server 500 error

Tags: python, django

I'm getting server error(500) after I set DEBUG to False, both in local and after deploying to Heroku.
Everything is Ok when DEBUG mode is True.

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting DEBUG = False causes 500 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128135/setting-debug-false-causes-500-error)

Comment: Unfortunately no..

Comment: Adding '*' to hosts did not work?

Comment: @cylee no that do not work too.

Comment: I have just figured out that some pages work, but some do not

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your logging and mail correctly so you see what exactly is happening.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

> Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse

`'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I have found the solution, the issue was with html template {% static %} tag.

I had such line

- link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/39-1109688-140x140.png' type="image/x-icon' %}"

but the closing %} must be in front of type

- link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/39-1109688-140x140.png' %}" type="image/x-icon"