# How to add media_root and media_url in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django 3, and I have tried every solution available on the internet, but none of them worked for me.
When I set DEBUG=False, I am unable to display an image on the HTML page.
Here are my settings

```
-root_app
--main_app
---settings.py
---asgi.py
---urls.py
---wsgi.py
--sub_app
---admin.py
---urls.py
---views.py
---static
----style.css
---templates
----home.html
---media
----images
```

media path in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'sub_app','media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Here what I have done to resolve it

- add context_processor
  `django.template.context_processors.media'`
- add  `+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in url_patterns of `urls.py` of sub_app
- I changed static storage to `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'`, otherwise I got 500 error. Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56259827/11170350)

But still, I am unable to display the image at `home.html` page.
When I click on image source using inspect element, I got this
`/media/images/img.png`

Answer (score 1):

These settings resolved the issue
Media Path

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sub_app','media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Static Path

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sub_app','static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

Adding re_path line in urls.py of main_app

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('sub_app.urls')),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, kwargs={'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'sub_app','media')
```

to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

in **settings.py** and use

```
{{MEDIA_URL}}images/image.png
```

inside your template.

Comment: this does not solve the problem. Even this does not load the broken image path. It just change the path of image being saved

Answer (score 0):

An edit to Dr. Abhishek's answer: yes, you need the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting, but you need to append it into the `STATICFILES_DIRS` list also, which will look something like this:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # ...
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]
```

When you load the image, use a soft-encoded path like this:

```html
{% load static %}
<!-- remember to change the file name/type! -->
<img src="{% static 'images/image.jpg' %}" alt="Image">
```

Comment: but this will create a new folder media, which will not be in static folder. then how it is supposed to work

Comment: if you don't mind, can you look at this [repo](https://github.com/talhaanwarch/Django_Image_Template) and let me know, what changes I have to make

Comment: what should be DIRS; path to the folder where HTML file is stored?

Comment: in my case it should be `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'sub_app', 'templates')]` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218097/discussion-between-crimsonpython24-and-talha-anwar).